# How to redirect from rails controller update action after a client (react) update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, axios, formik, react-rails

So I feel like this should be straightforward. I am using the react-rails gem to use some react in my rails app when needed. In this case, I am rendering a react_component form in the edit view. Once the update is complete (which takes place in react using axios), I want to use the rails controller to redirect to the index view which is not a react component. I would think a simple redirect to would work
example:

```
redirect_to users_path, notice: 'Update successful.'
```

But when my update is completed, the redirect thinks it is a 'put' request and fails with 404

```
PUT http://localhost:3000/users 404 (Not Found)
```

Is it possible to redirect from the rails controller? If not, what is the work around?

EDIT: fixed type user_path to users_path

Comment: http://localhost:3000/users is not the user_path, are you talking about redirect_to users_path? as you are using the Axios, maybe you can do the page redirect with window.location.replace

Comment: @FeifeiXiong that is a typo. It should say users_path. I could do a redirect in the client but my hopes were to avoid this and use rails.

Comment: sorry for the late response, yes, you can do it, since you are responding a js request, you should use format.js